# Android to Windows laptop file transfer via USB from app

Tags: android

I have business requirement where user wants to copy file from Android device into Windows 7 laptop via USB from android app(i.e. programmatically) because there is no wifi or cell data coverage available. I want to know if it is possible or not? How? Example would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look up [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), and from this you can do a simple script

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can think of would be storing the file in a specific location on the device's SD card (or internal memory), and then writing a program for the computer that copies the file from the device.